# How to import the employee's work hours to TimeScaleData in microsoft project file using vsto add-in

Tags: ms-project

How to import the employee's work hours to TimeScaleData in microsoft project file using vsto add-in?

Here is the sample data I have,

```
[{Name:"Phase 1", BaselineStart:"2023-01-01", BaselineFinish:"2023-03-30",
                Employees:[
                {Name:"John",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-12-01",Hours:6},{DateEntered:"2023-12-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-12-05",Hours:9}]},
                {Name:"Rosy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-11-04",Hours:2},{DateEntered:"2023-12-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-10-16",Hours:9}]}
                ]
            }]
```

Here is my code, but it giving me an error like `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is not valid.'` at this line  `Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(resource);`

```
Project project = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
Task newPhaseTask = project.Tasks.Add(phase.Name);
foreach (Employee emp in Employees)
{ 
 Resource resource = null;
 foreach (Resource projResource in project.Resources)
 {
     if (projResource.Name.Equals(emp.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         resource = projResource;
         break;
     }
 }
 if (resource == null)
 {
     resource = project.Resources.Add(emp.Name);
 }
foreach (var date in emp.EntryDates)
{
 foreach (Assignment assignment in newPhaseTask.Assignments)
 {
     if (assignment.Resource == resource)
     {
         assignmentExists = true;
         break; // Exit the loop if an assignment for the resource is found
     }
 }
 if (!assignmentExists)
 {
     // Create a new assignment for the resource on the task
     Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(resource);

     // Assign work hours to the specified date using TimeScaleData
     newAssignment.TimeScaleData(date.DateEntered, date.DateEntered, PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays, 1).Add(date.DateEntered, date.Hours);
 }
}
}
```